# Is there a size limitation to converting 3D array from C# to Matlab's MWNumericArray?

Tags: c#, matlab, matlab-compiler

I have a `c#` application that needs to send some data to `Matlab`. The data is a 3D array of `short`s.

```
short[,,] originalArray; It's value is: {short[532, 512, 512]}
```

My c# Conversion method looks like so:

```
public static MWArray ShortArrayToMWArray(short[,,] intArray, int v, int v1, int v2)
{
    try
    {
        //MWArray MW = new MWNumericArray(intArray);
        //return MW;
        MWNumericArray matrix = null;
        matrix = new MWNumericArray(MWArrayComplexity.Real, MWNumericType.Int8, v, v1, v2);
        matrix = intArray;
        return matrix;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        return new MWNumericArray();
    }
}
```

When I send in the whole thing, I get a very bizarre error message:

[image]

It's only when I started to play with the sizes that I started to doubt and ask this question. If I send in 1/4 of the array, it does the conversion (1/2 is still the same error):

```
// Copy 1/4 of the array into a tmp array    
Array tmpArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(short), originalArray.GetLength(0)/4, originalArray.GetLength(1)/4, originalArray.GetLength(2)/4);

System.Array.Copy(voxelArray, tmpArray, originalArray.GetLength(0)/4 * originalArray.GetLength(1)/4 * originalArray.GetLength(2)/4);

MWArray mwVol = MatlabUtils.ShortArrayToMWArray((short[,,])tmpArray, originalArray.GetLength(0) / 4, originalArray.GetLength(1) / 4, originalArray.GetLength(2) / 4);

System.Array.Copy(voxelArray, tmpArray, originalArray.GetLength(0)/4 * originalArray.GetLength(1)/4 * originalArray.GetLength(2)/4);

MWArray mwVol = MatlabUtils.ShortArrayToMWArray((short[,,])tmpArray, originalArray.GetLength(0) / 4, originalArray.GetLength(1) / 4, originalArray.GetLength(2) / 4);
```

Am I doing the conversion wrong?

Comment: What if literally disable the option from the error message (debugging->general->enable propery evaluation...), would it fix the issue? Btw in your example there is no `1/4` of array, it's `1/64 == (1/4)*(1/4)*(1/4)`

Comment: Are you compiling in 64 bit mode?  Open Task Manager and check memory as program executes to see if it is really a memory issue or limitation.

Comment: Disabling that option in VS does eliminate this error .. But this smells ..